# Multiple Kafka streams for spark streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

How to input kafka streams from two different topics (like view_event and click_event), how we can do this in Java so both the streams are received parallely. Till now I am trying this

```
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, GenericData.Record> stream_1 =
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, GenericData.Record.class, StringDecoder.class,
        GenericDataRecordDecoder.class, props, topicsSet_1);


JavaPairInputDStream<String, GenericData.Record> stream_2 =
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class, GenericData.Record.class, StringDecoder.class,
        GenericDataRecordDecoder.class, props, topicsSet_2);
```

But I observed some weirdness in output that sometimes only Stream_1 is received and only stream_2 is received.
Also I am using connector version 0.8.2.1 and I would be better if you provide sample code example.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Also, add what you have done so far to attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _"But I observed some weirdness in output"_ How do you observe the output? Note the outputs may get mixed because processing is on separate threads. How do you start your Spark app? What's the cluster manager?

Comment: How do you observe when data is received? Could you add that part of the code as well?

Comment: Observed the data using the spark streaming UI which was showing for the receivers that 0 events/sec.

Comment: could you add the rest of the code on how the streams are processed? If the receivers show 0 events/sec, then maybe there are no records being produced.